# Can we dynamically create a table in Oracle?

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, hibernate, jsp

First of all i want to say that the question i am going to ask is related to my project i.e student management system using Servlet and JSP using hibernate.
In my project i want to implement a functionality i.e. i will fetch the data from database of enrolled students of different streams together in a dynamic table on a JSP page and from there i will choose the 15 students of a particular stream by select the check box and using that selected students i want to create a batch means another table with a batch name. Means that one copy of that selected student will be added in the new table. This functionality will happen when administrator will click on create batch button.

Actually i am not able to implement this functionality. So if it is possible to implement then. Please Help!!

Note: I am using eclipse IDE and Oracle Database.

Comment: aren't you mixing all the layer of your application in one question? jsp doesn't have much to do with database development, or at least, shouldn't.

Comment: anyway, short answer: yes you can. medium answer: yes you can but you shouldn't, because usually the db user that fetch the data is not granted the right to alter the data structure (see ddl vs dml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you need to create a table dynamically???

If you are going for a relational database design, why not create a table called batch, insert a record of the new batch inside the Batch table and returns it's Identity (Primary Key), then also have created a junction table which links Students with Batch with a many-to-many relationship. Then you would insert a record in your junction table for each student selected for the batch using the Batch Primary Key and the Student's Primary Key values as a combined Primary key in your junction table.